# laravel 5.1 it is showing that Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, laravel-4, laravel-5.1

**fb calling api for uploading photos**

```
  <?php
  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
 'app_id' => '',
 'app_secret' => '',
 'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
  ]);

$data = [
 'message' => 'My awesome photo upload example.',
 'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel5-learning/public/image/share/'.$name),
 ];

 try {
 // Returns a `Facebook\FacebookResponse` object
 $response = $fb->post('/me/photos', $data, '{access-token}');
 } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
 echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
 exit;
}


$graphNode = $response->getGraphNode();

echo 'Photo ID: ' . $graphNode['id'];

  ?>
```

**classes I am using in my controller file**

**I think I need to include more classes that will work good. please help me in telling what I need to call**

```
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
    //use Session;
   //use Request;
   use DB;
   use DateTime;
    //use App\Locations;
    use App\Http\Requests;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

    use Facebook\Facebook as Facebook;
    use Facebook\FileUpload\FacebookFile;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
```

**is this showing this error that Class 'Facebook\Facebook' not found**

Comment: did you do composer require laravel/socialite ??

Comment: no... did it require this???

Comment: plz tell me how to do this laraval/socialite

Comment: yes, to use socialite your have add it in your composer .

Comment: did it solve the problem ?

Comment: no brother... i dont what exactly i have to write in composer

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/socialite use this .

Comment: ok... thanks i will use this

Comment: can you tell what exactly command i have to to write in my shell

Comment: composer require laravel/socialite

Comment: thanks man... write down in ans.. i will give u points

Comment: My pleasure buddy. I have written in answer please check .

Comment: ok done.. thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add socialite in your composer by using below command  .

```
composer require laravel/socialite
```

If you want to explore more then read [this](https://github.com/laravel/socialite)

Happy Coding :) .